# Which lightweight data grid to use?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, datagrid

I need a lightweight javascript data grid that doesn't require a ton of big files and one that  allows for paging and sorting to be done server side (requesting new data). I have tried several grids that load the full recordset in memory and then page and sort without making new requests, I don't like those. Also, inline editing, record search and ease of use would be a tremendous bonus. I'm using jQuery and server side c# 4.0 and sql server 2012.

Which grids do you have experience with that would fit the bill? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Datatables](https://datatables.net/)?

They offer some nice functionality out the box whilst also lending themselves to ajax calls to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few. I've found myself fond of DataTables lately:

https://datatables.net/

It's not heavy, it's powerful, it has many features, including the ones you need support.

Answer (score 0):

**[handsontable](http://handsontable.com/)** is by far the best data grid using jQuery.
It has inline editing, record search as well.

Comment: I can see **handsontable** more of a spreadsheet type than a data grid. Will have a go at **datatables** to find out how it fairs.